# Animation sub categories by hiding and showing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i'd like to animate the sub-categories in my code:
[code](http://pastebin.com/FxNrjp9Z) 
by showing it when i pass into the category name.but it didn't work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#m").hover(
   function () {
       $(this).children('ul').show();
      },
      function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
      }
   );

});
</script>
```

- what is the problem?
- how can i fix it?

Comment: but i don't know where is the error so i posted the hole code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching for children (ul) of an #m element, but there's not such children

You probably wanted to place that hidden `<ul>` into that `li` with id `m`

So just change

```
  <li id="m"><a href="#">Fine Photographs</a></li>
  <ul  class="hide">
    <li><a href="catalog_photographs_19.php" style="margin-left:2cm; width: 2cm;" >19th century </a></li>
    <li><a href="catalog_photographs_20.php" style="margin-left:2cm; width: 2cm;"  >20th century </a></li>
  </ul>
```

to

```
  <li id="m"><a href="#">Fine Photographs</a>
    <ul  class="hide">
    <li><a href="catalog_photographs_19.php" style="margin-left:2cm; width: 2cm;" >19th century </a></li>
    <li><a href="catalog_photographs_20.php" style="margin-left:2cm; width: 2cm;"  >20th century </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Yeah, that does the expected effect, doesn't it?